# How does NULL behaves with distinct keyword?

Tags: databases

Suppose I have a relation R

[image]

How many tuples are returned by SQL query

**SELECT distinct manager
FROM R**

Is it $2$ or $4$ ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: How about trying it out?

Comment: I tried running it. But it shows different behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You will get 2 records, with value 2 and null

NULL is still a value when it comes to distinct, but it is not included if you do a count,  so

```
select count(manager) from r;
```

would just return a count of 1